# Express.JS: req.params returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs, express

i have get method with route (Express & Node) which contains url params, and client side request on that url (react), but problem is that server is returning undefined for that params. here is code:

Server (index.js) :

```
router.use('/api/recipe/:dishName/:id', require('./view-recipe'))
```

view-recipe.js:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
      const name = req.params.dishName;
      const id = req.params.id;
      console.log('name ' + name +'  id  ' + id)
})
```

and client side (ReactJS):

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    console.log(`/api/recipe/${params.dishName}/${params.id}`)
    axios.get(`/api/recipe/${params.dishName}/${params.id}`)
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(data =>{
       console.log(data.recipe)
    })      
}
```

this code returns undefined for both: name and id on server side but client sid variables (params.id and params.dishName) works (i logged it and it is valid). by the way,

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

this error is shown in console
Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to access those values in `info.js` ?

Comment: i edited it (it was old code) but it did not work anyway

Comment: Have you tried moving your params to the actual route definition?
`router.use('/api/recipe, require('./view-recipe'))` / `router.get('/:dishName/:id', (req, res) => {
      const name = req.params.dishName;
      const id = req.params.id;
      console.log('name ' + name +'  id  ' + id)
})`

Comment: i did not. let me try it

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like:

```
var viewRecipe=require('./view-recipe')
router.use('/api/recipe/:dishName/:id',viewRecipe.get )
```

and in view-recipe.js:

```
module.exports={
 get:function(req,res,next){
   const name = req.params.dishName;
      const id = req.params.id;
      console.log('name ' + name +'  id  ' + id)
     ...rest of code
    res.send('something')
  }
}
```

The fundamental behind this is that you need to map the router twice to use a method.